# Letters only regular expression without numbers

Tags: regex

Guys let me know a regex which test only letters even without numbers.

```
^[a-zA-Z\s]+$
```

this will not work. It accept numbers as well

Comment: Please update your answer with the code you're using to actually try to match using this expression.

Comment: I got solved this. Thanks

Comment: Then you should post your solution or mark any existing answer correct.

Answer (score 1):

The expression isn't the problem, something else is wrong with your code that does the regex matching but you haven't included it with your question.

The expression is correct; It will not accept numbers. It will only accept one or more lowercase letters from `a` to `z`, uppercase letters from `A` to `Z` and spaces.

I have included a snippet you can run below to see the expression in action. Notice how the 2nd result returns `null`.

```
// matches, returns ["no numbers"]
console.log("no numbers".match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/))

// does not match, null
console.log("1 number".match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/))
```

Answer (score 1):

Whoever ventures into this thread and seeks an answer to this old but still useful question:

In this example I tried to match words without any numbers in them from an array of countless words and phrases. If you run the code you can clearly see that the words containing numbers won't match and therefore won't be posted. I added a change ".toLower()" so that any match is presented as a lower case word regardless of it being a noun or a verb as it does not matter for my case.

$arrayofwords = @("Thanks for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow!"; "Not the answer you're looking for? Browse other questions tagged"; "1asdasdfasd7";"asdasd7gadfs";"7th Street"; "RAL4051" )

$matchpattern = "\b[a-zA-Z]+\b"

[regex]::Matches($arrayofwords, $matchpattern) | ForEach-Object { $_.Value.ToLower() }